# Error out of nowhere: "Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'RaygunStatic' has no compatible call signatures."

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, raygun, raygun.io

We have an angular / ionic app using typescript with the raygun library installed.  Until today it has been building fine, just today I have started getting the following error when building

> "Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'RaygunStatic' has no compatible call signatures."

This happens on the following line of code

```
rg4js('setUser', {
```

At the top of the file I have

```
import * as rg4js from 'raygun4js';
```

I am compiling the exact same code from git a week ago that was working.  I am facing the same error locally and when running the build on ionic pro, which is extra strange as therefore it shouldn't be down to a version of anything on my machine changing since it was working a week ago in ionic framework and now it isn't, with nothing changing in the code.

Something has changed, but I can't figure out what.

I've reached out to raygun and they said:

> We do know that there are some issues with the definitions not
>   exporting all the correct information and we hope to fix this in the
>   future.

But I don't see why it would have worked last week and not today.  I haven't changed the version of the raygun library.

Any help appreciated.

Cheers,
Rob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A not so nice "fix" for this temporarily would be to mark the `rg4js` usage as any. Then the complier will ignore type-checking for this usage.

`(rg4js as any)('user', {...`

As to why it did work before and doesn't anymore I don't know. I've experienced the type checking saying everything was fine and complying when there was a bug but didn't look into it further at the time.

Comment: yeah, that's what I figured, I'd need to do something like that just to get the build working.  Thanks